# Not able to call value in the core files

Tags: users

I am working on a theme that display profiles I build a code according to theme - that it should display only limited profiles with the role queen and king.. I manage to open all the profile now the theme uses a themex.core.php file with all this information what to display and what not.. but I am really confused that this function

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $userr = new WP_User( $user_ID );
    if ( !empty( $userr->roles ) && is_array( $userr->roles ) ) {
        foreach ( $userr->roles as $rolee )
            $reguserr = $rolee;
    }
}
?>
```

is running normal on every page of the site but when I try to retrieve the value of $reguserr in the themex.core.php file I wasn't able to retrieve it what's going on can any body explain how I can get this work on those files ?

Comment: Please add what you expect the value of `$reguserr `to be, what the value of `$reguserr` is (including any errors with `WP_DEBUG` on), and how you're trying to output the `$reguserr` value.

Answer (score 0):

You'r following an bad idea.

What you would like to reallize is, displaying a few profiles, not all. It doesn't matter if the role is named "king" or "queen" even if your specific roles called so.

There is an better way to reallize such Kind of requirements: `Capabilities`. Add an `capabilitie` to WordPress and just give that view roles you would like to Display that `capabilitie`.
Then you are able to Change the Name of the role or define new "visible" roles without Messing arround with your code.